# Ударение в слове "каучук"

Tags: фонетика

И еще у меня вопрос по ударениям. Никак не могу определить до конца, как правильно: каучУк или кАучук? Слышала и так, и так.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из Резниченко: Правильно: каучУк. Это слово из языка американских индейцев был заимствовано русским языком из английского языка с первым ударным слогом, но это ударение не сохранило. Кроме того, в косвенных падежах это слово может иметь разное ударение: нейтральное постоянное  ударение "каучУка" и профес. "каучукА" с перемещением ударения на окончание.

Answer (score 2):

КаучУк правильно. Ударение на последний слог.